# How to get Values from foreach and return the same as an Array in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

This is my forEach loop ,now I want to take the ouput for each row and return the same in an array any sort of help is appreciated .
as of now I have tried something like this ,  like suppose I am expecting 2object from the response , but I am recieving only one object which is the second object or last object ,

```
    public Validation save(Multipart file){
       
          ArrayList<Item> dta = new ArrayList<>();
                IntStream.range(0, data.size()).forEach(rowNo-> {
                    try {
                   Item item   saveData(rowNo+2,data.get(rowNo),vlidation);
                 ret.add(item);
            });
            return dta;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: `forEach` is a terminal operation. If you want a collection from that, you should `map` it.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-map-examples/). You already have the stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some comments suggested you could solve this with streams, since you're already using them.

Simply map it and then call `collect(Collectors.toList())` to get a list.

```java
IntStream.range(0, data.size()).map(rowNo-> {
                    try {
                       return saveData(rowNo+2,data.get(rowNo),vlidation);
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        ..
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you do not want to use streams you could loop and add the current item to a list:

```java
ArrayList<Item> ret = new ArrayList<>;
IntStream.range(0, data.size()).forEach(rowNo-> {
                   try {
                      Item item =  saveData(rowNo+2,data.get(rowNo),vlidation);
                      ret.add(item);
                   } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ...
                }
            });
// ret is the list that you wanted
```

Comment: It didn't helped @Josip edited question for your refrence pls check

Comment: This probably means that saveData caused an exception on some items which means those items were not added to the ArrayList. Try to debug it.